# IEEE bibliography misordering references

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeetrantools

I'm using the IEEE Journal Overleaf template with the below header/footer lines. I'm also using a '.bib' file for the bibliography that is properly formatted. In the references section of the document, citation [27] is split between two columns (not unusual), but then citation [35] is out of order splitting apart [27] (screenshot attached). From testing of document length, switching/removing citations, etc., the problem appears to be with the IEEE format in the bibliography. The references always end at the same height, and the incorrect order occurs at different citations (e.g. [32] or [37] may be out of order instead). Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
HEADER:
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{widetext}

FOOTER:
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,main}
```

[image: Screenshot-of-references]

EDIT:
Thank you for the comments, I've copied the (edited, with specific filenames removed) output log along with a screenshot of Overleaf's output

```
output.log:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.30)  10 DEC 2022 19:50
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ieeetran/IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen138
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen139
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen140
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count182
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count183
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count184
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks16
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 503.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen141
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen142
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen143
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.
\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen145
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen146
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen147
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen148
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen149
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen150
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen151
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen152
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen153
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen154
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen155
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip47
\c@section=\count185
\c@subsection=\count186
\c@subsubsection=\count187
\c@paragraph=\count188
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count190
\c@table=\count191
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count192
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count193
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count194
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen156
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen157
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen158
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen159
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count195
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box50
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen160
\IEEEPARstartletwidth=\dimen161
\c@IEEEbiography=\count196
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen162
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen163
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count198
\leftroot@=\count199
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count266
\DOTSCASE@=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
\big@size=\dimen164
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count268
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count269
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count270
\dspbrk@lvl=\count271
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count272
\column@=\count273
\maxfields@=\count274
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen165
\alignsep@=\dimen166
\tagshift@=\dimen167
\tagwidth@=\dimen168
\totwidth@=\dimen169
\lineht@=\dimen170
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty
Package: bm 2021/04/25 v1.2e Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup6
\symboldletters=\mathgroup7
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup8
Package bm Info: No bold for \OMX/cmex/m/n, using \pmb.
Package bm Info: No bold for \U/msa/m/n, using \pmb.
Package bm Info: No bold for \U/msb/m/n, using \pmb.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 149.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/braket/braket.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package: caption 2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
)
\captionmargin=\dimen171
\captionmargin@=\dimen172
\captionwidth=\dimen173
\caption@tempdima=\dimen174
\caption@indent=\dimen175
\caption@parindent=\dimen176
\caption@hangindent=\dimen177
Package caption Info: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)             standard defaults will be used.
Package caption Info: \@makecaption = \long macro:#1#2->\ifx \@captype \@IEEEtablestring \footnotesize \bgroup \par \centering \@IEEEtabletopskipstrut {\normalfont \footnotesize #1}\\{\normalfont \footnotesize \scshape #2}\par \addvspace {0.5\baselineskip }\egroup \@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace \else \@IEEEfigurecaptionsepspace \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {\normalfont \footnotesize {#1.}\nobreakspace \nobreakspace #2}\ifdim \wd \@tempboxa >\hsize \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {\normalfont \footnotesize {#1.}\nobreakspace \nobreakspace }\parbox [t]{\hsize }{\normalfont \footnotesize \noindent \unhbox \@tempboxa #2}\else \ifCLASSOPTIONconference \hbox to\hsize {\normalfont \footnotesize \hfil \box \@tempboxa \hfil }\else \hbox to\hsize {\normalfont \footnotesize \box \@tempboxa \hfil }\fi \fi \fi  on input line 1139.
)

Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

\c@caption@flags=\count275
\c@continuedfloat=\count276
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 302.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 332.
Package: cite 2015/02/27  v 5.5
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count277
\float@exts=\toks23
\float@box=\box54
\@float@everytoks=\toks24
\@floatcapt=\box55
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/was/gensymb.sty
Package: gensymb 2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen178
\Gin@req@width=\dimen179
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks25
\inpenc@posthook=\toks26
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def
File: latin1.def 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
Package: mathtools 2021/04/12 v1.27 mathematical typesetting tools
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count278
\calc@Bcount=\count279
\calc@Adimen=\dimen180
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen181
\calc@Askip=\skip53
\calc@Bskip=\skip54
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count280
\calc@Cskip=\skip55
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
)
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\('isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\)'isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\['isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\]'isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count281
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen182
\origjot=\skip56
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen183
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen184
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen185
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen186
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen187
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen188
\xmathstrut@box=\box56
\xmathstrut@dim=\dimen189
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty
Package: subcaption 2020/10/07 v1.3j Sub-captions (AR)
\c@subfigure=\count282
\c@subtable=\count283
) (./widetext.sty
Package: widetext 
\wttlinewidth=\skip57
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count284
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and footers
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip58
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip59
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip60
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip61
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip62
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip63
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip64
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip65
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip66
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-07-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count285
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box57
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 48.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 48.
-- Lines per column: 58 (exact).
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \celsius on input line 48.
Package gensymb Info: Faking symbols for \degree and \celsius on input line 48.

Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \ohm on input line 48.
Package gensymb Info: Using \Omega for \ohm on input line 48.

Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count286
\scratchdimen=\dimen190
\scratchbox=\box58
\nofMPsegments=\count287
\nofMParguments=\count288
\everyMPshowfont=\toks27
\MPscratchCnt=\count289
\MPscratchDim=\dimen191
\MPnumerator=\count290
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count291
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks28
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/flushend.sty
Package: flushend 2020/10/16 v3.5 Balancing columns in twocolumn mode
\flushend@@lastskip@a=\skip67
\flushend@@lastskip@b=\skip68
\flushend@@lastskip@c=\skip69
\flushend@@penalty@a=\count292
\var@@loop@iter=\count293
\flushend@@lastkern@a=\dimen192
\var@@temp@spread=\dimen193
\var@@temp@a=\dimen194
\var@@temp@loop=\dimen195
\flushend@@page@rule=\dimen196
\flushend@@varbox@a=\box59
\flushend@@varbox@c=\box60
\flushend@@tempbox@a=\box61
\flushend@@tempbox@c=\box62
\@viper=\box63
\hold@viper=\box64
\atColsBreak=\toks29
\atColsEnd=\toks30
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/cuted.sty
Package: cuted 2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
\At@ViperColsBreak=\toks31
\v@aaa=\box65
\v@ccc=\box66
\lastskip@a=\skip70
\lastskip@b=\skip71
\lastskip@d=\skip72
\lastbox@a=\box67
\stripsep=\skip73
\viper@penalty=\count294
\ht@viper=\dimen197
)
\@parindent=\skip74
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 93.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 93.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
<figures/.png, id=1, 766.865pt x 414.54875pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 99.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 133.88545pt.
<figures/.png, id=3, 1084.05pt x 651.18282pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 106.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 227.04126pt x 136.37485pt.
<figures/.jpg, id=4, 449.42906pt x 224.33812pt>
File: figures/.jpg)
<use figures/.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.jpg  used on input line 112.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 113.52063pt x 56.66289pt.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}


]
Underfull \vbox (badness 2020) has occurred while \output is active []

[2 <./figures/.jpg>]
<figures/.png, id=29, 594.22pt x 593.21625pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 193.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 165.12378pt x 164.84122pt.

Underfull \hbox (badness 1394) in paragraph at lines 189--197
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Using this for-mu-la-tion, the curved sec-tion of the mid-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 2027) in paragraph at lines 189--197
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 helps re-duce mode mis-match losses and losses as-so-ci-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 2181) in paragraph at lines 189--197
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 ated with de-creas-ing radii of cur-va-ture. Us-ing $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 R[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 =
 []

[3 <./figures/.png>]

Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atop;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 259.

<figures/.png, id=34, 602.25pt x 451.6875pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 284.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 185.75822pt.
<figures/.png, id=35, 602.25pt x 451.6875pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 290.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 185.75822pt.
<figures/.png, id=36, 602.25pt x 376.40625pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 304.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 154.79852pt.
[4]
<figures/.png, id=41, 596.2275pt x 405.76593pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 314.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 165.12378pt x 112.37538pt.
<figures/.png, id=42, 1129.21875pt x 752.8125pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 320.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 165.11383pt.
[5 <./figures/.png (PNG copy)>]
Underfull \vbox (badness 3039) has occurred while \output is active []

<figures/.png, id=46, 934.49126pt x 499.8675pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 363.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 175.43811pt x 93.83932pt.
<figures/.png, id=47, 1199.48125pt x 499.8675pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 369.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 227.04126pt x 94.6097pt.
[6 <./figures/.png (PNG copy)>]
<figures/.png, id=52, 602.25pt x 376.40625pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 392.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 154.79852pt.
<figures/.png, id=53, 602.25pt x 376.40625pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 398.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 154.79852pt.
<figures/.png, id=54, 1606.0pt x 803.0pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 415.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 123.83882pt.
<figures/.png, id=55, 602.25pt x 376.40625pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 421.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 154.79852pt.
[7 <./figures/.png (PNG copy)>] (./appendices/.tex

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/ptm/m/scit' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/ptm/m/it' instead on input line 1.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/ptm/m/scit' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/ptm/m/it' instead on input line 1.

[8 <./figures/.png (PNG copy)>]) (./appendices/.tex
<figures/.jpg, id=66, 727.96968pt x 166.37157pt>
File: figures/.jpg)
<use figures/.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.jpg  used on input line 29.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 56.60365pt.
<figures/.png, id=67, 602.25pt x 376.40625pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 35.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 206.39685pt x 128.99876pt.
) (./appendices/.tex
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

[9 <./figures/.jpg>]
<figures/.png, id=71, 602.25pt x 338.76563pt>
File: figures/.png)
<use figures/.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: figures/.png  used on input line 43.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 247.6778pt x 139.31866pt.
) (./output.bbl [10 <./figures/.png (PNG copy)>]
Underfull \hbox (badness 2903) in paragraph at lines 109--112
[]\OT1/ptm/m/n/8 M. Wim-mer, A. Re-gens-burger, M.-A. Miri, C. Bersch, D. N.
 []

)
- LAST -
Extra skip:7.26807pt
Left:696.0pt/0.0pt
Right:480.0pt/1.73193pt
Output:480.86597pt
[11] (./output.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5942 strings out of 478542
 101234 string characters out of 5850413
 440180 words of memory out of 5000000
 23768 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 442690 words of font info for 98 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1144 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,18n,66p,2087b,466s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi5.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr5.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.pfb></usr/l
ocal/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmb8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmbi8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on output.pdf (11 pages, 1116060 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 151 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 79 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 91 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

[image: Overleaf-output]

Comment: Please give the complete code that can reproduce the one shown in your figure.

Comment: that shouldn't be possible, so  unless you provide an example it will be very hard to debug. Start by deleting the generated bibliography (`delete cached files` button in overleaf) so it makes a new one. Do you get an error from latex or bibtex, if so show  the error from the logs (`.log` or `.blg` file)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the suggestions. Unfortunately I cannot provide the complete code as this work is currently unpublished and not ready for public release (yet). I have updated the question with the output log. @DavidCarlisle, there was no error from latex or bibtex. A few warnings, granted, but everything else was working fine. I've attached a screenshot from Overleaf's output as well. Thank you for the help in figuring out what might be happening.

Comment: you can replace every word by `wibble` and still make an example.

Comment: /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin1.def looks wrong I think the overleaf editor is always utf-8 /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/cuted.sty can confuse 2 col modes especally with non standard classes

Answer (score 0):

Based on @DavidCarlisle's comments, I looked into the `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` package a bit more. For reasons currently unknown to me, using the 2021 (and 2020) `TeX Live version` (in the Overleaf Menu) causes an error **whereas the 2022 version** compiles the references correctly.